# How to know through which network interface ip address is pinged?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I am progrmmatically pininging ip address using c++ in windows.

I used the code from this link for pinging https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647/Ping-for-Windows

I am receiving reply from this function

WSAAPI
recvfrom(
    SOCKET s,
    char FAR * buf,
     int len,
    int flags,
    struct sockaddr FAR * from,
   int FAR * fromlen
    );

From this function, How to know through which local network interface I am receiving the reply or able to ping?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should `bind` that socket prior.

Comment: The ping reply is sent to the originating IP.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking how to determine the _local_ endpoint that received the ping reply or the _remote_ endpoint that sent the ping reply?

Comment: @Miles how to determine local endpoint?